# Скрипт не видит rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю скрипт для перемещения персонажа по урокам в интернете. Застрял на моменте прыжка. Unity выкидывает мне:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Пара моих тестов показала, что значение `rb` остаётся `null` после `start`. `Rigidbody` на тело нацеплен, само тело указано (но и до введения `public GameObject` было всё тоже самое)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainHeroContr : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1f;
    public float force = 1f;

    bool isGround = true;

    public GameObject srcrb;
    Rigidbody rb;

    void start()
    {
        rb = srcrb.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "ground") isGround = true;
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "ground") isGround = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("moveRight"))
        {
            transform.Translate(transform.right * speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetButton("moveLeft"))
        {
            transform.Translate(-transform.right * speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetButton("moveForward"))
        {
            transform.Translate(transform.forward * speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetButton("moveBack"))
        {
            transform.Translate(-transform.forward * speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && isGround)
        {
            print(rb);  
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы делаете перемещение тела, нужно пользоваться не `transform.Translate(transform.right*speed);`, а `rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed, 0, 0);`. А вы просто двигаете координату, что игнорирует физику столкновений.

Answer (score 1):

Замените `void start()` на `void Start()`.

[`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) у `MonoBehaviour` с большой буквы должен быть. Впрочем, по конвенции, все методы должны именоваться с большой буквы.